# Batch code to create incremental subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I am kind of new to Batch scripting, I am trying to write a script to create a folder which contains incremental subfolders increased by `15`.

My code so far:

```cmd
echo off
echo Testing to create a file to a directory and incremental sub folders

cd C:\Batch test
set folder=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%
mkdir %folder%
cd C:\Batch test\%folder%
set fol=%9810%
md "%fol%"
pause
```

The above code creates a folder with today's date and creates a sub folder called `810` , I want to create more sub folders with an increment of `15` eg. `825`, `840`, `855`, ...

Any help would be very well appreciated.

Regards

Dilip

Comment: in addition to Nikson answer, a couple of caveats, `cd` does not change the current drive, use `pushd` instead and wrap the directory with double quotes `"`. And `pushd` has the added bonus that you may later finish your batch with `popd` to restore the current drive and path.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using a loop, like following

```
 FOR /L %%I in (810, 15, 900) do (
    md %%I
 )
```

Detail [`FOR /?`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)